# Retrieving value with Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

How to retrieve value with Simple HTML DOM parser.

Example:

```
<td  class="tabData" valign="top"><a href="anouncement.asp?s=51&id=1635872">some string</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

I need value: `Some string`.

Problem are values `51` and `id = "1635872"` are not constant.

Comment: Please read the [`Manual`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)!

Comment: Please do not write tags in titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the DOM is in `$dom`:

```
$value = $dom->find("td.tabData a", 0)->plainText
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response ... i have tried your solution and it gives me an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I've added the second argument to `find` so it will return a single element instead of an array.